# Incorrect message processing of PromptDialog.Choice()?

Tags: c#, botframework

I noticed that using `PromptDialog.Choice()` to begin a conversation proactively is not working as expected and wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if it is a problem in the bot framework.

I'm using the prompt in my root dialog like this:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    PromptDialog.Choice(...);
}
```

The problem is that for the root dialog multiple messages arrive. There are at least two "conversation updated" messages, one for adding the bot, another for adding the user.

The prompt dialog interprets those as answers and of course they don't match the available prompt choices. So the prompt dialog does one more attempt and shows itself again. As a result, I always get multiple prompts on conversation start.

I tracked it down to the message handler in the [dialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/4621a4c611889a6ebade4717329f8e6ea62f2f7f/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L1160) and saw that it does not check the message type. As a workaround I have created my own prompt dialog which ignores all non-message type activities and now it is working as expected:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomPromptDialog : PromptChoice<string>
{
    public CustomPromptDialog(string title, params string [] buttons) : base(
        new PromptOptions<string>(prompt: title, retry: "", tooManyAttempts: "", options: new List<string>(buttons), attempts: 2, promptStyler: null))
    {
    }

    protected async override Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message)
    {
        var activity = await message;

       // This is what is IMHO missing in the built-in version.
        if(activity.Type != ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            return;
        }

        await base.MessageReceivedAsync(context, message);
    }
}
```

Am I using the prompt incorrectly or is it a bug in the framework?

Comment: Can you add the code of your MessageController? You should not route your ConversationUpdate messages to your dialog

Comment: Well, that's the thing: if I want to show the choice dialog proactively, I must react to _something_ and that means the conversation update; I don't want to wait for the first incoming user message. I really would have to show the prompt dialog on the _last_  incoming conversation update but how would I know how many there are?

Comment: You just have to filter the conversationUpdate throwing the dialog, by using a check on `message.MembersAdded: the Id should be different from `message.Recipient.Id` to exclude the bot. That's why I asked for the code of your MessageController ;)

Comment: D'oh! Yeah, that was it! I'll add an answer to this myself. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: In fact that's a duplicate that should be raised as this question has been posted several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As replied in comment, the solution for your case is to launch your Dialog containing the `PromptChoice` only when you are notified that a `user` is joining the conversation.

For that case you can check the `MemberAdded` info inside `conversationUpdate` message, and launch your dialog only when the added member is not the bot, that is to say the Id of the member is not equal to the Id of the bot, which is `message.Recipient.Id`:

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
    if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id != message.Recipient.Id))
        {
            // Your PromptChoiceDialog here        
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: The question was flagged as duplicate, why an answer was added?

Comment: @EzequielJadib it wasn't at the time of the answer, and even if I flagged it (I wasn't sure it would be finally marked as duplicate), I added the answer because there is also a small change versus the answer of the duplicate, because the test must check if the Id is different, not equal.